# When I see math.stackexchange and multirow formulas, I could imagine hexagonal molecular structures here

Tags: discussion

Could such schemes be implemented here with keyboard input (like Japanese glyphs or math input)?

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: I'd rather have a graphical editor, like [I proposed at the beginning](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3/7).

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, it really would be a nice thing to have...

On the other hand, I can't see if it would be worth the dev time -- moleculer structures are rarely used--if we need them, we can draw them and upload (loads of free drawing software out there). On the other hand, math formulae (and chemical equations, which work here), are needed quite a bit and it would be impractical to  image-ify each and upload. Another thing is that there aren't any good ways to draw chem figures with keyboard input. SMILES isn't that human-friendly; it's hard to draw a complex figure in SMILES. Or any other such structure-encoding language, for that matter -- because of its nonlinear nature. So there's still be a lot of effort to add a molecular structure.

I *do* have a plan to modify an open source online structure drawing software into a popup-based thing so that the devs don't need to do much work to add it. Unfortunately, it's on my back-back-back-backburner ;)

Either way, no harm in keeping the suggestion out there, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I like using the $\LaTeX$ package "chemfig." Have you considered adding this package?

It is a nice way to use $\LaTeX$ to draw figures quickly without too much of a learning curve. If we add "\usepackage{chemfig}" to the preamble, the $\LaTeX$ command "\chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-\lewis{26,O}-H}" would draw:

[image: ethanol]

Comment: Thing is, MathJax isn't LaTeX and we can't just `\include` like that. ChemFig would have to be explicitly coded in :/ You may propose this feature [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues?state=open)

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining this!